# Matplotlib Interactive subplots with integers and dates on X axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I am trying to create two interactive plots where the first plot is simply a plot of `x` and `y` and the second plot is a subplot which plots dates (fulldate) on its x axis, which correspond to the integer values of `x` (x axis values) from the first plot.

This code almost does what I want. The only problem is that the dates are not linked to the integers, so when I use the zoom function on the graph, it zooms into the first plot and the subplot is linked and zooms also, **but** the dates stay stationary and therefore are completely inaccurate.

note that this is just a simplified version of my program. i will be rearranging the dates on the bottom display to got on the bottom.

The integers and the dates must be linked because in my actual program i will be using integers to keep count of the days in the time series.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


x=[1,5,7,4,6]
y=[1,3,8,4,6]
fulldate=['01/01/2018','02/01/2018','03/01/2018','04/01/2018','05/01/2018']

with sns.axes_style("darkgrid"):

      ax1=plt.subplot2grid((6,1),(0,0),rowspan=3,colspan=1)
      ax2=plt.subplot2grid((6,1),(4,0),rowspan=1,colspan=1,sharex=ax1)
      ax2v = ax2.twiny()


      ax1.plot(x,y)
      ax2v.fill_between(fulldate,'Dates')
      for label in ax2v.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
          label.set_rotation(60)
```

Comment: What are the integers used for? Do you need to show them? Or wouldn't it be enough to only see the dates at the bottom?

Comment: No, it would not be enough. i'm creating a special display where i need both the integers and the corresponding dates in the time series to be interactively shown. sorry for being pedantic, but that's what i need :)

Comment: To see what you need and in how far it fails, it would be good to have the dates defines inside the code as well. By "interactively" you mean you want to be able to zoom and pan the plot as well?

Comment: You are right, i have made and edit and defined fulldate. by interactive i mean that when i zoom into the first plot, it should zoom into the second plot too. it does that, but the relative position of the dates doesn't change

Comment: I have fixed a few other things that i missed. you should see now what i mean if you run the code

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr5Ao.png) really almost what you want?

Comment: yes, i will be relocating the dates to go at the bottom and i will get rid of the integers from the bottom display, but all of that should be easy. the problem is the zoom

Comment: If the two plots are supposed to be zoomed together, there must be a relationship between the integers and the dates. I don't quite see this relationship here. I.e. what does 7 have to do with 05/01/2018?

Comment: I have just recreated a simplified example. the integers in my actual application will be a means to keep count of the amount of days. this is a very long time series that will be read from a CSV.

Comment: I think I need to give up here. Without any relationship between the two scales there is not much one can do. This is rather a logical problem than an implementation problem.

Comment: the logic is crystal clear. i have described everything perfectly. and it must be done this way

Comment: Still you don't get an answer, because people don't understand it. It's like one of those riddles, "7 is the 5th of january, what is 19?"

Comment: I added more explanation to my post. hopefully people will find it easier to understand now lol